# Checking if a user input already exists in the table before updating

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm relatively new to django and trying short cash flow project for a petrol station.I know very basic html and i am trying to improve the user experience with my limited knowledge.

Currently, I have various forms (totalling around 7 - with a few being formsets) with each form being located in a different page.

```
SalesForm = modelformset_factory(DailySales, extra = 2, exclude=('Date','Gross_sales'))
RatesForm = modelformset_factory(DailyRates,extra = 1, exclude = ('Date',))
class loose2tForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = loose_2t
        exclude = ('Date','Amount',)

Other_revenue_form = modelformset_factory(Other_revenue,extra = 1, exclude = ('Date',))
Credit_details_form = modelformset_factory(Credit_details,extra = 1, exclude = ('Date',))
Expenditure_form = modelformset_factory(Expenditure_details,extra = 1 , exclude = ('Date',))
```

I've structured the flow in a way that a user gets redirected to the next form as soon as he submits the current form details.

The problem occurs when the form is a formset. lets say

1. I entered details for a single row for the model and clicked submit(i invoked form.save() in the view and django saves it to the model)
2. I go back and add another row in the formset and clicks submit - The model has 3 rows - 1 that was already saved and 2 more which are saved when i clicked on submit the second time.

I'm not sure where exactly i should look in the documentation to solve this.

KJ

Comment: Edited post.does sending a pre save signal to a function storing all the required data and committing at the final step work?